# Как задать таймер боту

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Есть скрипт который постит на стену вк, но нужно чтобы он постил каждый час, сначала я подумал поместить в `while` c `time.sleep(3600)`, но что-то не то

Скрипт:

```
import vk_api
import sys
import random


# Скрипт помещает картинки на стену пользователя vk.com


def vk_auth(login, password):
    vk = vk_api.VkApi(login, password)

    try:
        vk.authorization()  # Авторизируемся
    except vk_api.AuthorizationError as error_msg:
        print(error_msg)  # В случае ошибки выведем сообщение
        sys.exit()

    return vk


# Логин, пароль к аккаунту и id человека, на стену которого будем постить сообщения
LOGIN = ''
PASSWORD = ''
OWNER_ID = ''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Авторизируемся
    vk = vk_auth(LOGIN, PASSWORD)

    # Список с ссылками на картинки
    hrefs = [

    ]

    # "Перемешаем" элементы списка
    random.shuffle(hrefs)

    # Добавление сообщения на стену пользователя
    # Если не указывать owner_id, сообщения себе на стену поместится
    for href in hrefs:
        rs = vk.method('wall.post', {
            'owner_id': OWNER_ID,
            'message': 'Хей!',
            'attachments': href,
        })
        print(rs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте **[schedule](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule)**:

```
import schedule
import time
import vk_api
import sys
import random


# Скрипт помещает картинки на стену пользователя vk.com


def vk_auth(login, password):
    vk = vk_api.VkApi(login, password)

    try:
        vk.authorization()  # Авторизируемся
    except vk_api.AuthorizationError as error_msg:
        print(error_msg)  # В случае ошибки выведем сообщение
        sys.exit()

    return vk


# Логин, пароль к аккаунту и id человека, на стену которого будем постить сообщения
LOGIN = ''
PASSWORD = ''
OWNER_ID = ''



def job():
    # Авторизируемся
    vk = vk_auth(LOGIN, PASSWORD)

    # Список с ссылками на картинки
    hrefs = [

    ]

    # "Перемешаем" элементы списка
    random.shuffle(hrefs)

    # Добавление сообщения на стену пользователя
    # Если не указывать owner_id, сообщения себе на стену поместится
    for href in hrefs:
        rs = vk.method('wall.post', {
            'owner_id': OWNER_ID,
            'message': 'Хей!',
            'attachments': href,
        })
        print(rs)

schedule.every().hour.do(job)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Поместить содержимое main в функцию и вызывать ее в цикле с нужной задержкой

```
...

import time

def work(vk):
    # Список с ссылками на картинки
    hrefs = [

    ]

    # "Перемешаем" элементы списка
    # Или: href = random.choice(hrefs)
    random.shuffle(hrefs)
    
    # Возьмем первую ссылку
    href = hrefs[0]

    # Добавление сообщения на стену пользователя
    # Если не указывать owner_id, сообщения себе на стену поместится
    rs = vk.method('wall.post', {
        'owner_id': OWNER_ID,
        'message': 'Хей!',
        'attachments': href,
    })
    print(rs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Авторизация
    vk = vk_auth(LOGIN, PASSWORD)

    while True:
        work(vk)
        
        # Каждый час
        time.sleep(60 * 60)
```

Answer (score 0):

Реализуйте в своём сценарии отправку единичной записи и заведите [cron](/questions/tagged/cron), добавив примерно такую строчку в его глобальный файл конфигурации

```
0 * * * * your-user /path/to/your/script
```

Это будет запускать ваш сценарий в начале каждого часа.