# Отправить каждые 30 минут комментарий вк

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

нужна программа (не для спама), которая в сообщество, под определенный пост отправляла бы раз в 30 минут слово стоп в комментарии

Я пытался написать её на python и все время не удачно

Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: приведите пример кода.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как задать таймер боту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/703780/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%83)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

От лица сообщества:

```
import vk_api
import schedule
import time


def com():

    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(
        token='токен группы')

    vk = vk_session.get_api()
    vk.wall.createComment(owner_id='-id группы', post_id='id поста',
                          from_group='id группы от кого комментарий', message='стоп')
com()


schedule.every(30).minutes.do(com)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Либо от лица пользователя:

```
import vk_api
import schedule
import time

def com():

    login, password = 'логин от аккаунта', 'пароль от аккаунта'
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login, password)

    try:
        vk_session.auth(token_only=True)
    except vk_api.AuthError as error_msg:
        print(error_msg)
        return

    vk = vk_session.get_api()
    vk.wall.createComment(owner_id='-id группы', post_id='id поста', message='стоп')
com()


schedule.every(30).minutes.do(com)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: без токена это возможно осуществить? И отправлять не от имени сообщества, а от имени личной страницы?

Comment: Добавил правку в свой ответ, посмотри, сделал комментарий от имени пользователя.